# Angular/jQuery necessary for single webpage application?

Tags: jquery, spring, angular

I am planning to do a Single-Page-Webapplication. Is it possible to achieve that with server-side SpringMVC framework and Thymeleaf template engine only or do I also need some client-side stuff like Angular or jQuery additionally? The goal is to prevent of having to reload the whole web page every time something changes and provide the user a desktop-application-similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** you can't build a SPA with only `SpringMVC` and `Thymeleaf`.

Unfortunately `Thymeleaf` is a server side template engine that is used to build pages in the server, that means that it relay on redirects and reloads unlike SPA's,

If you want to build an SPA application either use something like `Angular` or combine `Thymeleaf` with something like `Angular` to enjoy the benefits of both.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wide array of choices to build a single page app.

To answer your question:

> Is it possible to achieve that with server-side SpringMVC framework
>   and Thymeleaf template engine only?

Yes. And No.

You may use SpringMVC to return the initial single page view (index.html) and later use basic Javascript to make XMLHttpRequests to your JSON REST services exposed using SpringMVC. You will need to deal with the DOM manipulation in JavaScript for rendering every element required as per design.

Optionally, you may write your services in away which accept a template parameter, which specifies the template you wish to use to render the response of the service. So the rendering of the response happens on the server side using Thymeleaf, and the server responds back with the HTML data from an AJAX request. You can then attach the HTML from the response as the required DOM.

But the above explained approach is prone to bugs and you will try to reinvent the wheel (eg. history, form submission, url routing, unit testing etc.) when all this stuff is readily available in modern Javascript frameworks such as Angular, Ember or React.

So, it is better you start with a good framework, but the learning curve for each of these frameworks is quite steep. If you are comfortable with jQuery, you might as well make use of it for a start, if the app is not complex enough.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your goal is to prevent of having to reload the whole web page every time something changes and provide the user a desktop-application-similar experience.

This cannot be achieved by using Server side applications as in server side application the request goes to the server and the server responds back with the appropriate page which take some time to load.

For the user to have a desktop like experience , you have to build a SPA using Angular (i suggest) as it is trending in the market with a good user community .

My Take on the solution would be a Spring based RestFul Web service and a Angular frontend

I you want to learn some concepts of Angular please look at this page

https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts